# How to convert SO2 mol/m2 to µg/m3

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

How do I convert SO2 mol/m2 to µg/m3 ?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2')
.select('SO2_column_number_density')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31')
// .filterMetadata("SO2_column_number_density", 'less_than', 0);
.map(function(image){return image.updateMask(image.gte(0))})
// print(collection)
// var col=collection.values.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['SO2_column_number_density']))
print(collection)
var no2Image = collection.mean().clip(geometry); // mean across each period
print('NO2 image', no2Image); // debug info in console
var band_viz = {
min: 0,
max: 0.004,
opacity: 1,
palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
// The region of interest - a planar rectangle around London/S.England.
var rect = geometry
Map.setOptions('hybrid'); // set map to hybrid backdrop
Map.centerObject(rect, 6); // zoom in to the defined area
Map.addLayer(no2Image, band_viz, 'Sentinel 5P NRT N02 - Nov 2019');
// Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
// commented out here - but saves off geoTIFF files
Export.image.toDrive({
image: no2Image.clip(rect),
description: 'SO2_red_sea_december',
folder: 'GEE',
fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_change',
region: rect,
fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
scale: 1000
});
```

Code source:
[Filter negative SO2 image collection in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389387/filter-negative-so2-image-collection-in-gee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Molecular weight of SO<sub>2</sub> is 64.066 µg/µmol so, for converting mol/m<sup>2</sup> to µg/m<sup>2</sup> the factor is 64.10<sup>6</sup> because there are 1,000,000 µmol in a mol. The third dimension is the column height for converting m<sup>2</sup> to m<sup>3</sup> (it looks like a prism with square base). If you want to consider the height, you should to multiply each value for this parameter (if not, obtained values will be expressed in µg/m<sup>3</sup> until 1 m height; as in following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/37a64d1b5123e5e9e35080a82ac05138)).

In your code, you should modify as follows for obtaining values expressed in µg/m<sup>3</sup> (change the height value for different altitude of column density).

```
// define a 'collection' of images

var height = 1;

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12,12,'month'))

  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2021-05-31')
  // .filterMetadata("SO2_column_number_density", 'less_than', 0);
  .map(function(image){
    return image
      .multiply(64.066E6)
      .multiply(height)
      .updateMask(image.gte(0))});
```

After running the code in above link, I got following result for an arbitrary point in your roi.

[image]