# Generating time series chart using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p

How can I plot the chart to show the SO2 time series?

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2')
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2021-10-01', '2021-10-31')
  // .filterMetadata("SO2_column_number_density", 'less_than', 0);
  .map(function (image) { return image.updateMask(image.gte(0)) })
// print(collection)
// var col=collection.values.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['SO2_column_number_density']))
print(collection)
var no2Image = collection.mean().clip(geometry); // mean across each period
print('NO2 image', no2Image); // debug info in console
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.004,
  opacity: 1,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};
// The region of interest - a planar rectangle around London/S.England.
var rect = geometry
Map.setOptions('hybrid'); // set map to hybrid backdrop
Map.centerObject(rect, 6); // zoom in to the defined area
Map.addLayer(no2Image, band_viz, 'Sentinel 5P NRT N02 - Nov 2019');
// Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
// commented out here - but saves off geoTIFF files
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: no2Image.clip(rect),
  description: 'SO2_red_sea_december',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_change',
  region: rect,
  fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
  scale: 1000
});
```

Code source: [Filter negative SO2 image collection in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389387/filter-negative-so2-image-collection-in-gee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details you can check this [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection).

One way:

```
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .doySeries({
          imageCollection: collection,
          region: geometry,
          regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 1113.2,
          startDay: 1,
          endDay: 365
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['SO2_column_number_density'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average SO2 by Day of Year',
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Day of year',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          vAxis: {
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['1d6b99'],
        });
print(chart);
```

[Code link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/62dc5b894c57b737f03d0050b77e30db)